# How to return the best model in a Keras callback function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to modify my callback function to do early stopping with `keras`.

**The goal is to train my neural network by using the following rules :**

- Train until the loss function is under a given baseline and the number of epochs is higher than a given threshold.
- If that condition is not fulfilled, return the model having the lowest loss function value.

I know how to handle the first condition but I don't know how to deal with the last one.

Would you like to help me ?

Thank you.

Here is my code :

```
    def __init__(self, monitor='loss', baseline=0.05, min_epochs=500):
        super(EarlyStoppingCustomized, self).__init__()
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.baseline = baseline
        self.min_epochs=min_epochs

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        loss = logs.get(self.monitor)
        if loss is not None:
            if loss <= self.baseline and epoch >= self.min_epochs:
                self.model.stop_training = True
```

Comment: Use EarlyStopping callback to stop the training if the metric you are monitoring reaches a treshold. Also use ModelCheckpoint with the argument ```save_best_only=1``` to save the best model at each training iteration.

Comment: At https://keras.io/callbacks/

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/tmp/weights.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

Comment: Thanks guys but I do not understand how to combine EarlyStopping and ModelCheckpoint. I mean, how to set the callback parameter of the fit method of a keras model ?

Comment: ```model.fit(..., callbacks=[EarlyStopping(...), ModelCheckpoint(...)])```.  ```callbacks``` argument can be a sequence of callback objects

Comment: Hum, I am afraid that ModelCheckpoint will keep the best model even if it appears with an epoch lower than the patience. If this is the case, it will probably be bad as it will not let the time to my neural net to train correctly. Let's assume that patience=50 and at epoch=50 the situation is given by val_loss = 0.1 (minimum) with train_loss = 0.3. ModelCheckpoint will give the model that reached it. The train loss will be not good as the number of epochs is not high.. Is that correct ? In this case, how to avoid such a situation ?

Comment: You can monitor for example validation loss with EarlyStopping and train loss with ModelCheckpoint so the training will halt when validation loss reaches the threshold but save the model with minimum train loss. You need to tune the ```monitor``` argument in both callbacks.

Comment: I have to admit that I do not how callback works. If I give it [Early.., Model...], does it mean that it will first run EarlyStopping and if EarlyStopping parameters don't allow to stop earlier, it will run ModelCheckpoint ? I am a bit lost...

Comment: I made a test. I set up a model with two callbacks, my own callback implementation, and a EarlyStopping one. I put EarlyStopping first in the list. It seems ```on_epoch_end``` is invoked on every callback before the model training halts due to patience reaching the limit

Comment: Here is the dummy test: https://pastebin.com/7wTzf88J  Hope that clarifies your question